# Using jquery ajax load in place of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to use jquery load function with ajax as an alternative to using iFrame.

My Code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upQnA" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="dQnA" style="position:relative" title="QnA" >

                                QnA</div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        $("#dQnA").load("http://www.google.com", function (responseText, statusText, xhr) {
                                           if (statusText == "success")
                                               alert("Successfully loaded the content!");
                                          if (statusText == "error")
                                               alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
                                        });
                                    });
</script>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmLanding" EventName="Tick"/></Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But when I click on the search button of google page, the page gets refreshed and instead of results `QnA` is displayed. I want to know how to keep the code behind functionality of the page loaded in the div using jquery load function.

Comment: this is not jquery code this is ajax update panel of microsoft...check for ajax jquery reuest on google

Comment: @PranayRana I'm not saying this is jquery code. I'm saying that I'm jquery load function in my .net code. I'm unable to use the functionality of any page that is being loaded into the asp panel whether google or local aspx page.

Comment: than it may be conflict between both library